# Sorting alphanumerically with a twist

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort a field alphanumerically in the database. It turns out to be trickier than I thought. This is just example values, the content can vary, but I hope it's enough to get the idea.

I want to sort this list:

```
11
01
1
1A
01B
20a
01a
20
1b
2b
02a
```

Like this:

```
1
01
1A
01a
1b
01B
02a
2b
11
20
20a
```

Note that the relative ordering of equivalent numbers with and without leading zeroes is not important, it can be `1 01` or `01 1`.

I've tried `CAST(field AS UNSIGNED)` but it doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: What are your rules for sorting ?   eg, why does 2b come before both 11 and 20 ?

Comment: @racraman Looks like it's sorting by the numeric prefix first, then the length of the numeric part (to handle leading zeroes), then the alphabetic suffix.

Comment: Because the letters are different versions of the digits. So 2 comes first, 2a and 2b are versions of that. In other words they should come before 11 and 20.

Comment: OK, so '11' and '20' are eleven and twenty, so come after 2.  So in summary, you're looking to split the field into 3 substrings (a: optional leading zero(s), b: number as sequence of digits, c:optional letter suffix), then sort by a,(b converted to integer),c - yes?

Comment: So...sometimes 2 characters count as 1 character for sorting? Can these character modifying characters occur in the middle of the string, or only at the end?

Comment: Yes, 01, 00001 and 1 are all before 2, as 02 is before 3 etc. and if you have the  same string but a letter at the end, the letter should come last: 120 is before 120A

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? You can use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function to extract the numeric prefix and alphabetic suffix.

Comment: If not, you'll need to write a function to do it, as there are no built-in functions to find the position of a character set, you can only look for specific strings.

Comment: It says `mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407` from `phpinfo()` so I guess not?

Comment: Is it the leading zeroes that makes it tricky? As long as 01 and 1 comes before 2, they can come in any order among themselves if that helps at all. 01, 1 or 1, 01

Comment: That's the PHP MySQL driver version, not the version of MySQL.

Comment: Oops, is there an easy way I can find out? Not good at the server stuff. It's an Ubuntu server at Digital Ocean that someone helped me set up.

Comment: Execute the query: `SELECT version();`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, no luck :( `5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

Comment: So, there are no possibility that the alphabetical character occurring in the beginning or in the middle of the value? like 'A1' or '0A1'?

Comment: Potentially, but 99.5% of the time no so it’s fine if that’s a dealbreaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 8.0 or higher, you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(colname, '[a-z]+$')` to get the alphabetic suffix, and `CAST(colname AS UNSIGNED)` to get the numeric prefix. Then you can sort by these.

```
SELECT code
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CAST(code AS UNSIGNED), REGEXP_SUBSTR(code, '[a-z]+$')
```

See [What is the equivalent of REGEXP_SUBSTR in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742650/what-is-the-equivalent-of-regexp-substr-in-mysql) for how to get similar functionality in earlier versions of MySQL.

Another possibility is:

```
ORDER BY CAST(code AS UNSIGNED), TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM code)
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks nice and simple. Can anyone help me translate that into older MySQL? I checked out the link, but not sure where to start.

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you. If you can't do it yourself, you need to hire a more competent programmer.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound ungrateful. I've spent 20 minutes on the page you linked, but just doesn't know how to do it. I was hoping that this would have been an easy `CAST()` thing. I just created folders named the exact same names as I listed in my original post, guess what, Mac OS X is sorting it exactly the way I want as default, so I'm surprised that there isn't an easy way to do it in MySQL. Check out this screenshot: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhc34h119led6el/sorting.png?dl=0)

Comment: There's no easy solution for this. Did you see the answer that contains a link to a `PREG_CAPTURE()` user-defined function?

Comment: Yes, sorry I just don't know what to do with it. I found this post. It looks like it's called "natural sorting" what I'm after. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257917/3234322

Comment: Natural sorting is useful when you want to sort by letters first, then numbers. You're going the other way.

Comment: I might just go for 'CAST(field AS UNSIGNED), field'. It doesn't solve the leading zeroes, but most of the time it will be one or the other anyway so I can live with it. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @SeaBass I tried that, but it didn't give the desired result.

Comment: You could try `CAST(field AS UNSIGNED), TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM field)` to ignore the leading zeroes.

Comment: I've tried that @Barmar but there are a few places where the ordering is off. For example, the first row should return '1' then '01' but instead with `ORDER BY CAST(field AS UNSIGNED), TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM field)`, it returns '01' first then '1'. I did however successfully order the results as OP's specified ASSUMING that the alphabetical characters only occurred at the end of every value .. using this `ORDER BY CAST(code AS UNSIGNED),RIGHT(code,1),LENGTH(code), TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM code)` .. adding to your original ordering suggestion

Comment: @tcadidot0 He said the relative ordering of `1` and `01` doesn't matter.

Comment: @tcadidot0 It was in a comment, I just copied it into the question.

Comment: Oook, sorry, I clearly missed that. In that case my suggestion is just to cater the exact OP's desired result only.

Comment: @tcadidot0 Awesome! Thank you!