# Why does a reg expression match not work while ordering in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This question can be thought of as related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832734/query-to-order-by-the-last-three-characters-of-a-column). If I had the same table:

| ID | Name | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ashley | 81 |
| 2 | Samantha | 75 |
| 3 | Belvet | 84 |
| 4 | Julia | 76 |

And I wanted to sort on last three characters, then why wouldn't this query work:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM students
    where Marks > 75
    ORDER BY Name regexp "[a-z]{3}$" ASC;
```

Do regular expression work while sorting? When I do run this query I get no errors whatsoever but there is no sorting as well. What I get is this:

Comment: Add `Name regexp "[a-z]{3}$" ` to the select list and see what's returned. (Standard trick when having order by issues.)

Comment: It does not return any error but returns a new column with 1s as values.

Comment: `REGEXP` returns the **starting index** of the substring of the string expr that matches the regular expression specified by the pattern pat, or **0** if there is no match. It does not return the string. You are looking for `REGEXP_SUBSTR` [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: @ontrack *REGEXP returns the starting index of the substring of the string expr that matches the regular expression specified by the pattern pat, 0 if there is no match.* Who tells this to you???

Comment: I  think REGEXP matches the whole string pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work for me in Oracle.

```
with students (id, name, marks) as(
select 1,   'Ashley',  81 from dual union all
select 2,   'Samantha',    75 from dual union all
select 3,   'Belvet',  84 from dual union all
select 4,   'Julia' ,  76 from dual)
SELECT
    regexp_substr(name, '[a-z]{3}$')
FROM
    students
ORDER BY
    regexp_substr(name, '[a-z]{3}$');
```

Comment: Using a similar query in MySQL gives error REGEXP_SUBSTR does not exist: ```select REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name, "[a-z]{3}$") from students
    where Marks > 75
    order by REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name, "[a-z]{3}$") ASC;```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742650/what-is-the-equivalent-of-regexp-substr-in-mysql

Comment: Ok got it working. regexp_substr() in the order by clause.

Answer (score 1):

All values matches the pattern.

> ```
> with students (id, name, marks) as(
> select 1,   'Ashley',  81 from dual union all
> select 2,   'Samantha',    75 from dual union all
> select 3,   'Belvet',  84 from dual union all
> select 4,   'Julia' ,  76 from dual)
> SELECT *, 
>        Name regexp "[a-z]{3}$" AS ordering_expression 
> FROM students
> ORDER BY Name regexp "[a-z]{3}$" ASC;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name     | marks | ordering_expression
> -: | :------- | ----: | ------------------:
>  1 | Ashley   |    81 |                   1
>  2 | Samantha |    75 |                   1
>  3 | Belvet   |    84 |                   1
>  4 | Julia    |    76 |                   1
> ```

So the rows are not sorted.

> ```
> -- test 6-letter pattern
> with students (id, name, marks) as(
> select 1,   'Ashley',  81 from dual union all
> select 2,   'Samantha',    75 from dual union all
> select 3,   'Belvet',  84 from dual union all
> select 4,   'Julia' ,  76 from dual)
> SELECT *, 
>        Name regexp "[a-z]{6}$" AS ordering_expression 
> FROM students
> ORDER BY Name regexp "[a-z]{6}$" ASC;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name     | marks | ordering_expression
> -: | :------- | ----: | ------------------:
>  4 | Julia    |    76 |                   0
>  1 | Ashley   |    81 |                   1
>  2 | Samantha |    75 |                   1
>  3 | Belvet   |    84 |                   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce3760e93382cf2a7c39ca1cdf25c0da)*

---

> 'Ashley' should come first because 'ley' < 'lia'. – shiv_90

> ```
> with students (id, name, marks) as(
> select 1,   'Ashley',  81 from dual union all
> select 2,   'Samantha',    75 from dual union all
> select 3,   'Belvet',  84 from dual union all
> select 4,   'Julia' ,  76 from dual)
> SELECT *
> FROM students
> ORDER BY RIGHT(Name, 3) ASC;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name     | marks
> -: | :------- | ----:
>  1 | Ashley   |    81
>  4 | Julia    |    76
>  2 | Samantha |    75
>  3 | Belvet   |    84
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa7a864410a2548bc88f0cf906a45f52)*

Comment: 'Ashley' should come first because 'ley' < 'lia'.

Comment: @shiv_90 If so then REGEXP not needed.